# Multicasting with Raspberry Pis as clients

Tags: linux

I attached an image and in the image, I have a network of two Cisco routers and three Raspberry Pis. I want to implement multicast routing. I have already configured the dynamic routing protocols and achieved full connectivity. To implement multicasting, I have issued both multicasting command globally on both routers, enabled IGMP on the interfaces concerned with the multicasting and connected directly to the Raspberry Pis through the switch.

The issue I am having here is knowing the IGMP command for the Raspberry Pis to join the multicast group. I have googled a lot and I saw this command `sudo ip route add <multicast-group-address> dev <interface>` which i edited to this `sudo ip route add 232.1.1.1 dev eth0`. I rebooted the Raspberry Pi and when it came on I ran the command `sudo ip mroute` and nothing displayed. I honestly am really confused.

I have Googled a lot and I saw this command `sudo ip route add dev`  which i edited to this `sudo ip route add 232.1.1.1 dev eth0`. I rebooted the Raspberry Pi and when it came on I ran the command `sudo ip mroute` and nothing displayed. I honestly am really confused.